# Помогите найти определение

Tags: словообразование, словоизменение

Добрый вечер. Помогите найти определение. Определение такое: человек предъявляет ко всем правила и нормы но к себе это не относит. Т.е. к кому то он предъявляет какое то поведение но сам себя так не ведет.
Я забыл как это называется, помогите вспомнить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Т.е. к кому то он предъявляет какое то поведение но сам себя так не ведет. Я забыл как это называется, помогите вспомнить.

**Ханжа.**

Возможно подойдут такие слова, как *двойные стандарты, лицемерие*.

Comment: Спасибо огромнейшее, это было слово ханжество.
"Как пишет Ноам Хомский, ханжа (лицемер) — это тот, кто прикладывает к другим стандарты, которые отказывается применять к себе"

Comment: Пожалуйста. Заходите ещё.

Answer (score 0):

Похоже на фарисейство.

В переносном, конечно, значении.